# Comparing dates to allow an action if 24 hours or more has elapsed

Tags: c#

I need to compare two dates to allow an action only when 24 hours, or a day, has elapsed. I am using the TimeSpan object to compare dates

If there is a date of April 4th and May 5th, would this count as 1 day or 30 or so days?

Effectively, I need to have the latter logic. What's the best way to do this?

My code is:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - user.LastPasswordSet.Value;

int days = ts.Days;

if (days >= 1 )
```

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried it with those two dates? Can't you answer this question yourself?

Comment: Why would it count as 1 day? Also, you probably want `TotalDays` as opposed to `Days`.

Comment: `if ((DateTime.Now - user.LastPasswordSet.Value).TotalHours > 24)` ?

Comment: One note - you may want to use UTC datetimes to save having to worry about what happens when clocks change and so on.

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan.Days will give the Day portion of the result.

TimeSpan.totalDays will give you the entire duration measured in days and as it returns a double you also get the fraction.

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - User.LastPasswordSet.Value;

        double days = ts.TotalDays;

        if (days >= 1)
        {
            //A day has passed.
        }
```